# r metafor: extract random effects from multivariate model

Tags: r, meta-analysis

Is there some function like ranef() or some other approach to extract the random effects from a multivariate model using metafor::rma.mv function?
 Here's the example provided by the oficial website of the package.

```
dat <- get(data(dat.berkey1998))
V <- lapply(split(dat[,c("v1i", "v2i")], dat$trial), as.matrix)
V <- bldiag(V)
res <- rma.mv(yi, V, mods = ~ outcome - 1, random = ~ outcome | trial, struct="UN", data=dat)
res
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, haven't gotten around to implementing `ranef()` and `blup()` for models fitted with `rma.mv()` yet. It's on my to-do list, but I cannot say when I will get this done.

**Update:** The `ranef()` function now (as of version 2.0-0) works for `rma.mv` objects (not yet `blup()`).

Comment: Any updates as of 7/5/2017?

Comment: @RMurphy See updated answer.